# Why am I not able to use Xlookup in Microsoft Excel 365?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

Hi Iam using MS Excel 365, I have a problem in using Xlookup, however while i try to use the formula typing manually I get the following error:

[image: Error message]

Comment: What build are you using.  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 0):

According to [XLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929), XLOOKUP function is a new feature available in Excel for Office 365, Excel for Office 365 for Mac, Excel for the web.

Note: November 25, 2019: XLOOKUP is currently **a beta feature**, and only available to a portion of Office Insiders at this time. Office team will continue to optimize it over the next several months. When XLOOKUP is ready, Office team will release it to all Office Insiders, and Office 365 subscribers.

If your Excel for Office 365 is in a common channel(Monthly Channel, Semi-Annual Channel, Semi-Annual Channel (Targeted)), you can't use XLOOKUP function currently.